# When is it worth to set in Xcode > General > Team and is it worth to leave empty?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am curious, when do I need to set / change `Team` setting in my project.

Is it Project based setting or relating all the projects opened in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: All projects I expect as it relates to your Apple Developer Account.

Comment: I always turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows Xcode to automatically download and create provisioning profiles, certificates, provision devices etc. If you're developing on the simulator you don't need to turn it on. If you have an iOS developer program account add it in Xcode's preferences and then select it here. In the old days all the stuff you had to do manually through the developer center now gets done automatically by setting the team in Xcode. The reason it is a dropdown is incase you are a member of multiple developer programs (e.g. a freelancer or a business account and a personal account). You can then choose the team based on the project you're working on.

Comment: Do I have to set up Provision Profiles in Developer Portal at all? Or Xcode will generate it? Is it enough to create App IDs?

Comment: When it works Xcode generates everything. If there's an issue it usually presents a button below 'team' labeled 'fix' and it will automatically create the required files in the developer center and download them. If you're developing using a device and intend to distribute I would recommend turning it on. I always have it on.